# Can CefSharp browser navigation be avoided after custom protocol handling?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, custom-protocol

I have a simple custom protocol scheme that I want to use
with CefSharp to "start" a file in Windows.  The scheme works,
but I can't find a way to prevent chromium from navigating to
that file url (after it's been invoked successfully by Process.Start
in the code below).  I've tried just about every combination of
CefReturnValue and callback.Dispose and request.Dispose

Here's the code:

```
public override CefReturnValue ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ICallback callback)
{
    var uri = new Uri(request.Url);
    string requestedPath = WebUtility.UrlDecode(uri.AbsolutePath);

    if (requestedPath.StartsWith("///"))
        requestedPath = requestedPath.Substring(3).Replace("/", @"\");

    if (File.Exists(requestedPath))
        Process.Start(requestedPath);

    callback.Dispose();
    return CefReturnValue.Cancel;
}
```

Does anyone know how to prevent the subsequent navigation?

Comment: You cannot prevent the navigation from ResourceHandler,  you can use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnBeforeBrowse.htm and cancel the navigation.

Comment: Technically `CEF` has a specific handler for this scenario, unfortunately it's broken currently https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2715/onprotocolexecution-page-goes-blank-after

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to amaitland, here's that answer --

Summary: Who needs a custom protocol?

Detail:

```
public class Program
{
    // stuff ...

    var settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme { SchemeName = "eutp"});

    // more stuff ...

    Cef.Initialize(settings);
}

public class EutpRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser,  IBrowser browser,
        IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
    {
        if (request.Url.StartsWith("eutp://file///")) {
            string requestedPath = WebUtility.UrlDecode(request.Url.Substring(14));
            requestedPath = requestedPath.Replace("/", @"\");
            if (File.Exists(requestedPath))
                Process.Start(requestedPath);

            return true; // cancel navigation
        }
        return false; // allows navigation
    }
}
```

Thanks again to amaitland for pointing out that a custom protocol scheme *factory* or *handler* is superfluous.  Only the scheme's *name* is required.

Comment: Do you actually need the `SchemeHandlerFactory`? I would have though just registering the scheme would have been sufficent.